# Steps to setup Eclipse che on Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, eclipse-che

I am trying to create an ECS container for eclipse che.
Can you please help with the steps to do the same.

i am able to setup Che on EC2 but not able to do the same on ECS

Comment: How you are setting up on ECS?

Comment: Not able to figure it out, tried uploading the Eclipse/Che image to ECR and start a container from it. It didn't work